# How to use transform-origin in CSS for below example?

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
 
#container{
  margin: 10rem;
  position:fixed;
}

.inner{
  animation: animate-inner 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate-inner{
  0%{
    transform-origin: 20% 20%;
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100%{
    transform-origin: 20% 20%;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.inner2{
  animation: animate-inner2 7s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate-inner2{
  0%{
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100%{
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg height = "500" width="500">
    <circle class="outer" cx="100" cy="100" r = "100"/>
    <circle class="inner" cx="93.5" cy="12.5" r = "12.5" fill="red"/>
    <circle class="outer" cx="400" cy="100" r = "100"/>
    <circle class="inner2" cx="393.5" cy="13.5" r = "12.5" fill="red"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

How to make use of transform-origin property in CSS? I have read MDN but I'm unclear how it use it in this case. I want the inner circle to circle the outer circle for both the circles. How to set the value so it inner circle circles both the outer circles. Any help.

Comment: For the second circle use `transform-origin: 80% 20%;` In order to understand what is happening draw a small circle `<circle  cx="20%" cy="20%" r = "5" fill="gold"/>`and another one `<circle  cx="80%" cy="20%" r = "5" fill="gold"/>`. Observation: I would put the transform-origin inside the roule for the element NOT inside the animation.

Comment: Any reason for this : I would put the transform-origin inside the roule for the element NOT inside the animation. How did you come up with 80% 20% ?

Comment: 80% 20% is where the center of the black circle is.  That's why I sugested to draw those small golden circles. You want the rotation to happen around the center of the black circle

Answer (score 0):

I think that `transform-origin` is making this more difficult. I added a `<g>` element as a parent element to each inner circle. This moves the circles to the center of each outer circle. Then I use `cx` as an "arm".

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
 
#container{
  margin: 10rem;
  position:fixed;
}

.inner{
  animation: animate-inner 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate-inner{
  0%{
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg height="500" width="500">
    <circle class="outer" cx="100" cy="100" r="100"/>
    <g transform="translate(100 100)">
      <circle class="inner" cx="87.5" r="12.5" fill="red"/>
    </g>
    <circle class="outer" cx="400" cy="100" r="100"/>
    <g transform="translate(400 100)">
      <circle class="inner" cx="87.5" cy="0" r="12.5" fill="blue"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```